# local collection types not allowed in sql statement (IN query)

Tags: plsql

i have a simple plsql query with me and i want to run fetch records from the table by passing array in in query.
below code is subprogram of a big program.

```
declare
  -- some array say item_array (2d dynamic dynamic array)
begin
  -- filled some records in array item_array say 1 to 10
  select id from demo where item in (item_array(1)); 
end;
```

please help.
i need such approach to caluclate frequent itemsets(data mining using apriori close) from table, when we calculate frequent itemsets for more transaction_ids.

if possible we can also store the result in the array.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use the [`ANY` keyword](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-SEARCHING) with the array.

```
SELECT id FROM demo WHERE item = ANY (item_array[1]);
```

The above assumes--as the comment suggests--that the `item_array` is two dimensional and you wanted the first element's array to search against.

Also note that when you are [accessing the array's individual elements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING), then you use square brackets rather than parentheses.

While I have never done so, if it's an `INOUT` parameter, then I do not see why you could not modify the array and therefore return it. However, I am not convinced that you have given a good reason to do this; just because you can do something does not make it the right way to do it.